# how to get the date from a class to the test class

Tags: java, arrays, date, mainclass

here is what i have to do, and what I have already did

After a quick meeting with the head of the company, you got the following information:

- It is required to store the whole data in one collection
- Each flight has a number, a pilot and a specific date. In addition, passengers could be added or removed within a given limit for the maximum number of passengers who could be in the same flight. Furthermore, there are other attributes (add at least 3 attributes from your choice). Of course, flight number is unique within the same date.
- Each pilot has a unique ID, a name and other attributes (add at least 2 attributes from your choice).
- Each passenger has a unique passport number, a name and other attributes (add at least 2 attributes from your choice but one of them should be common with pilots).

Moreover, you have been informed that the following operations happen frequently:

- Offering a new flight
- Adding a passenger to a specified flight
- Removing a passenger from a specified flight  Retrieving the average number of passengers per flight of a specified date
- Displaying all available flights in a format similar to the following: date1: flightNo1 flightNo2 flightNo3 … date2: flightNo1 flightNo2 flightNo3 … … where dates and flights are sorted in ascending order
- Saving all the data into a text file

this is what did

I am starting the test class and when I started I for some reason couldn't get the date so I tried a shitty way and I don't think I am right

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Testclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date1 = new Date("11/12/2020");
        Flights a = new Flight(1, date1, 50, 5, "saudi air", "complimentary");
        
}
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Flight {

    final List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();
    int number;
    Pilot pilot;
    Date date;
    int maxPassengers;
    int minPassengers;
    String airline;
    String food;

    public Flight() {

    }

    public Flight(int number, Date date, int maxPassengers, int minPassengers, String airline, String food) {
        this.number = number;
        this.date = date;
        this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
        this.minPassengers = minPassengers;
        this.airline = airline;
        this.food = food;
    }

    public List<Passenger> getPassengers() {
        return passengers;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Pilot getPilot() {
        return pilot;
    }

    public void setPilot(Pilot pilot) {
        if (!pilotExistance(pilot)) {
            this.pilot = pilot;
            System.out.println("Pilot has been added.");
        }
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getMaxPassengers() {
        return maxPassengers;
    }

    public void setMaxPassengers(int maxPassengers) {
        this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
    }

    public int getMinPassengers() {
        return minPassengers;
    }

    public void setMinPassengers(int minPassengers) {
        this.minPassengers = minPassengers;
    }

    public String getAirline() {
        return airline;
    }

    public void setAirline(String airline) {
        this.airline = airline;
    }

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public boolean pilotExistance(Pilot newPilot) {
        boolean pilotExist = false;
        for (Flight flight : Airport.flights) {
            if (flight.getPilot() != null && flight.getPilot().getId().equals(newPilot.getId())) {
                pilotExist = true;
                System.out.println("Pilot id: " + newPilot.getId() + " pilots in plane of flight number: " + flight.getNumber());
                break;
            }
        }
        return pilotExist;
    }

    public boolean passengerExistance(Passenger newPassenger) {
        boolean passengerExist = false;
        for (Flight flight : Airport.flights) {
            final List<Passenger> passengers = flight.getPassengers();
            for (Passenger passenger : passengers) {
                if (passenger.passportNumber.equals(newPassenger.passportNumber)) {
                    passengerExist = true;
                    System.out.println("Passenger with passport number: " + newPassenger.getPassportNumber() + " are on the flight with the flgit number: " + flight.getNumber());
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (passengerExist) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return passengerExist;
    }

    public void addPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        if (passengers.size() < maxPassengers) {
            if (!passengerExistance(passenger)) {
                passengers.add(passenger);
                System.out.println(" Included.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The Max number of passengers has already been reached.");
        }
    }

    public void removePassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        if (passengers.size() > minPassengers) {
            if (passengerExistance(passenger)) {
                passengers.remove(passenger);
                System.out.println("Passnger has been taken out of flight.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Passnger with passport number: " + passenger.getPassportNumber() + " doesn't exist.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The lowest amount of passengers have been reached.");
        }
    }

    public void passengersInformation() {
        if (passengers.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("There are no passengers.");
        } else {
            for (Passenger passenger : passengers) {
                System.out.println(passenger.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Number: " + number + ", Pilot: " + pilot != null ? pilot.toString() : "No pilot yet" + ", Date: " + date + ", airline: " + airline + ", food: " + food + ", Number of passengers: " + passengers.size();
    }
}

public class Passenger {

    String passportNumber;
    String name;
    String bloodtype;
    String agecatagory;

    public Passenger() {

    }

    public Passenger(String id, String name, String bloodtype, String agecatagory) {
        this.passportNumber = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.bloodtype = bloodtype;
        this.agecatagory = agecatagory;
    }

    public String getPassportNumber() {
        return passportNumber;
    }

    public void setPassportNumber(String passportNumber) {
        this.passportNumber = passportNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBloodtype() {
        return bloodtype;
    }

    public void setBloodtype(String bloodtype) {
        this.bloodtype = bloodtype;
    }

    public String getAgecatagory() {
        return agecatagory;
    }

    public void setAgecatagory(String agecatagory) {
        this.agecatagory = agecatagory;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Passport Number: " + passportNumber + ", Name: " + name + ", Bloodtype: " + bloodtype + ", Age catagory: " + agecatagory;
    }
}

public class Pilot {

    String id;
    String name;
    String experiancelevel;
    String pilotcatagory;

    public Pilot() {

    }

    public Pilot(String id, String name, String experiancelevel, String pilotcatagory) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.experiancelevel = experiancelevel;
        this.pilotcatagory = pilotcatagory;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //This function to get pilot id
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getExperiancelevel() {
        return experiancelevel;
    }

    public void setExperiancelevel(String experiancelevel) {
        this.experiancelevel = experiancelevel;
    }

    public String getPilotcatagory() {
        return pilotcatagory;
    }

    public void setPilotcatagory(String pilotcatagory) {
        this.pilotcatagory = pilotcatagory;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + id + ", Name: " + name + ", Experiance level: " + experiancelevel + ", Pilot catagory: " + pilotcatagory;
    }
}

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Airport {

    public static final List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<>();

    public Airport() {
    }

    public List<Flight> getFlights() {
        return flights;
    }

    public boolean flightExistance(Flight newFlight) {
        boolean flightExist = false;
        if (!flights.isEmpty()) {
            for (Flight flight : flights) {
                if (flight.date.equals(newFlight.date) && flight.number == newFlight.number) {
                    flightExist = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        return flightExist;
    }

    public void addFlight(Flight flight) {
        if (!flightExistance(flight)) {
            flights.add(flight);
            System.out.println("Flight Included.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number of flight: " + flight.getNumber() + " already in place.");
        }
    }

    public void averageNumberOfPassengersPerFlight(Date date) {
        int passengersCount = 0;
        int flightsCount = 0;
        double average = 0.0;
        for (Flight flight : flights) {
            if (flight.getDate().equals(date)) {
                flightsCount++;
                passengersCount += flight.getPassengers().size();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of passengers in the flight: " + passengersCount);
        if (passengersCount > 0 && flightsCount > 0) {
            average = passengersCount / flightsCount;
            System.out.println("Average number of passengers per flight for the specific date(" + date + "): " + average);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Average number of passengers per flight for the specific date(" + date + "): " + 0.0);
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        final List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Flight flight : flights) {
            if (!dates.contains(flight.getDate())) {
                dates.add(flight.getDate());
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(dates);
        for (Date date : dates) {
            System.out.print(date + ": ");
            final List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Flight flight : flights) {
                if (flight.getDate().equals(date)) {
                    numbers.add(flight.getNumber());
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(numbers);
            for (int number : numbers) {
                System.out.print("flightNo." + number + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("---------");
        }
    }

    public void saveInTextFile(String filePath) {
        try {
            final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
            for (Flight flight : flights) {
                writer.write(flight.toString());
                writer.write("\n");
                writer.write("---------");
            }
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Saved successfully");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Number of flights: " + flights.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I suggest you use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`, as the latter is obsolete and [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

Comment: Also, with what exactly are you stuck? You *"can't get the date"* – what happens, does it throw an exception? Does it output an incorrect date? Please provide more details.

Comment: it says "int cannot be a Date" when it's clearly a date

Comment: Have you recompiled the whole thing? It looks like you're indeed passing a `Date`, but apparently, the runtime disagrees.

Comment: That’s a large amount of code. Would it be possible that instead you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Answer (score 0):

i'm here to learn but i had a time limit so with the case of using Local time, I don't want to use code that I still don't understand yet so I just continued with what I did, it kinda sucked how I had to make a new object for each time but it's wasn't too bad and I finished the main method.

here it is(of course this isn't the last version as i added many more variables and commands but i just wanted to give you the final draft before i finished it completely.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //    public Flight(int number, Date date, int maxPassengers, int minPassengers, String airline, String food) {
    Date d = new Date("11/12/2020");
        Pilot h = new Pilot("qw2563", "zaid", "epxerianced", "main pilot");
        Pilot h1 = new Pilot("qw2563", "zaid", "epxerianced", "main pilot");
        Pilot h2 = new Pilot("qw2563", "zaid", "epxerianced", "main pilot");

        Flight f = new Flight(1, d, 50, 5, "saudi air", "complimentary",h);
        
        Passenger one = new Passenger("23546785", "ahmad", "B+", "adult");
        Airport hq = new Airport();
        hq.addFlight(f);
        f.addPassenger(one);
        f.addPassenger(one);
        
        
        
        
        
        

       
    }
    
}
```